# golang reading text input over more than one line and stop ctrl+s

Tags: input, go, readlines

How can I read more than one line in golang, console input.

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

fmt.Println("Enter Text:")

text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
```

How I must change ReadString(???) to stop reading if the user hit: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
The New Line (`\n`) must remain a constituent of the input.

Is there some library/framework for that?

Thanks for every help.

Cheers

Comment: Do you mean as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24296318/6309?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer for Linux (and could work for other *nix platforms)

`Ctrl+S` is a control character `DC3`, it means "XOFF, stop sending". If you press `Ctrl+S` the terminal would freeze.

`Ctrl+Q` is a control character `DC1`, it mean "XON, continue sending", it is necessary after `Ctrl+S` to unfreeze.

To use the `Ctrl+S`, first disable `XON/XOFF` with `stty -ixon` (maybe in in startup script)
After disabling `XON/XOFF`, the sample code is following (`DC3` is HEX:13/DEC:19 in ASCII table);

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println("Enter Text:")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\x13')
    fmt.Println(text)
}
```